# How can I optimize this code to print in this format?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, optimization, time-complexity

I want to print a linked list like this:

```
0       1       2       3       4
12      24      36      85      48
```

My current code is

```
void LinkedList::printList()
{
    curr = head; //store head in curr to irerate
    int count = 0; //counter to help uer manipulate list
    while (curr != NULL) //traverse whole list
    {
        cout << count++ <<"\t"; //print index
        curr = curr->next; //move to next 
    }
    curr = head; //make current head again
    cout << endl;//go to next line
    while (curr != NULL) //traverse whole list
    {
        cout << curr->data << "\t"; //print data
        curr = curr->next; //move to next 
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I am pretty sure there's another way to do this is a simpler and faster way. I want to reduce the redundancy on this code.

I am showing the counter to help user add or delete numbers.

Comment: How big are the numbers in the data and are you printing out every 5 numbers?

Comment: Updated the code is linked list of fixed size? I assumed this while presenting a solution

Comment: Given your list is small (if it were big, your screen showing the output would have to be big as well ;) ), you could do with 1 time traversal instead of 2 traversals and using 2 instances of ``std::ostringstream``, you could create the count and element value strings at the same time, then output them in the end after the loop.

Comment: If you want to print line-wrapped output, you'd work in small chunks.  Save a pointer to the current position while you walk the list out to `max_per_line` and print indices (checking for NULL).  Then print a newline and walk the list again.  Or instead of re-traversing the list, copy the list data you're going to print into a small array.  Or format on the fly like BitTickler suggests.  This makes sure that even long lists won't cause problems, because you'll only operate on them in small chunks.

Comment: @TahTatsumoto Its just for practice stuff, so not really big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you mean by "optimize".  Linked lists are inherently suboptimal for traversal because of poor cache locality.  Even less optimal is converting integer data to text and writing to a stream.

So I can only conclude that you wish to reduce code redundancy and consider that to be an optimization, even if it's at the expense of execution time.  One possible solution is to accept a function that is applied to each element:

```
void LinkedList::forEach( std::function<void (node*)> fn )
{
    for( node *curr = head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next )
    {
        fn( curr );
    }
}
```

And now you can use this to print node data or other stuff:

```
void LinkedList::printList()
{
    int count = 0;
    forEach( [&count]( node * ) { cout << count++ << "\t"; } );
    cout << endl;
    forEach( []( node *n ) { cout << n->data << "\t"; } );
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Note that a similar approach could be used by defining a custom _forward iterator_ for your class, and then using standard language features (like `foreach`) or functions from `<algorithm>` to operate on your list.  Making a custom iterator is a little more involved than the proposed solution, however.  So I've left it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <sstream>
void LinkedList::printList(std::ostream& os = std::cout) {
    size_t counter = 0;
    std::ostringstream indx;
    std::ostringstream value;
    for( ListNode *current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next ) {
        indx << counter++ << "\t";
        value << current->data << "\t";
    }
    os << indx.str().c_str() << std::endl << value.str().c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

- Only one List traversal
- for-loop instead of while.
- Speed does not matter as your list is supposedly tiny (unless you have a very very wide screen or a tiny tiny font), as you expect the content of the list to neatly fit into 1 line of your output window.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using ANSI escape codes for moving the printout position, and do it all in one loop.
http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html

Comment: This is only useful for terminals that support ANSI, and would not be appropriate for long lists.  Writing to a stream would be a mess.